# How do I auto renew my AWS certificate and why wont it accept the new one I assigned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have setup AWS to manage my SSL through ACM. I use ELB to route my traffic from HTTP to HTTPS. I am trying to renew an expired certificate. I created a new one got it validated through DNS and then assigned it via ELB. But it will still not show up when going to my site: dreamprojects.co

Any help troubleshooting is much appreciated.

Tried renewing the cert a few times. added *.dreamprojects.co and *.www.dreamproject.co but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Is dreamprojects.co your domain or you have mentioned as an example here?
This doesn't seem like to point to ELB but directly pointed to EC2 instance.

> dig dreamprojects.co +short
>   13.59.145.97

The cert presented when accessing dreamprojects.co issued by Lets Encrypt and expired.
ELB provides DNS name which you need to add it as a CNAME record because IP gets changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Im not an expert with this so thank you for your patience. Previously, I had created an Elastic IP and associated that with EC2 which is the 13.59.145.97, I also previously had my DNS setup like this on Porkbun: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz7x36vtnzj691z/Screenshot%202019-05-30%2011.02.48%20%28edited-Pixlr%29.jpg?dl=0) Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The ALIAS names you see here are the ELB DNS Names.

Comment: You have pointed the domain and www to EC2 instance IP so the ELB cert isn't effective at all, you need to point them to ELB DNS name you get, the only problem you may see that you can't have CNANE record for apex/naked domain, but if you DNS provides allows you to do that, you don’t need those A records but the Alias records are enough, even though you have created Alias record but for some reason they’re not affective and I still get EC2 address IP address, you should have only alias records , try to see if you can fix it.

Comment: otherwise a sample solution would be to 
renew or get a new Lets encrypt certificate, it's free and you can write a cronjob to auto renew it. https://www.onepagezen.com/letsencrypt-auto-renew-certbot-apache/

Comment: Ok so I tried deleting the A records and I get the following error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: Perfect, the records are pointed to ALB and the 503 is causing because the instance registered with ALB isn't passing health check. You need to make sure it passes health check , rest certificate is good. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html

Comment: It seems like you have redirection set on EC2, try to change health check status code to 302 and make sure you have target group on  https/port443 otherwise, it'll be a loop.

Comment: Ok sorry for this but I have attempted to move my DNS from Porkbun to Route 53. So currently I have attempted to point everything there. See screenshot: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2l7swg5ubrl4vuw/Screenshot%202019-05-30%2012.56.02%20%28edited-Pixlr%29.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: I associated the Route 53 with the ELB.

Comment: Ok so here is what I have done...I created a new target group [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gva1e2olvey0sty/Screenshot%202019-05-30%2013.29.46.png?dl=0) and then I set a new rule on the https/443 [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/liirr6rs7gwu0bt/Screenshot%202019-05-30%2013.32.17.png?dl=0) I am now seeing the Bitnami page...I suppose that is good. But I dont see my website.

Comment: Have you registered the same instance with ip 13.59.x.x for elb ?

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I ended up giving up on this sorry to have wasted your time. I moved over to WP Engine and it was way smoother. Up and running like 1 hour as opposed to all the head smashing against a wall i did with AWS.